# How to do a time range search in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, kibana-4

We are using the ELK for log aggregation. Is it possible to search for events that occured during a particular time range. Lets say I want to see all exceptions that occurred between 10am and 11am in last month.

Is it possible to extract the time part from @timestamp and do a range search on that somehow (similiar to date() in SQL)?

Comment: Is Kibana's time range selector near the top-right corner what you're looking for?

Comment: @MagnusBäck hi no I meant I would like to search for all events that occurred between say 10 and 11 am on all day during last month. So I am looking for an "additional" time range filter/query param to add on top of the range selector. any idea?

Comment: Oh, I see. I believe that's possible with a scripted field. I've seen examples of it (possibly in Elastic's blog) but I don't recall the details.

Comment: @MagnusBäck thanks I ll do a google run on that...

Comment: Can't you just do this? 
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "@timestamp": {
        "gte": 1478511000000,
        "lte": 1478514600000
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisBeauchef no I meant to search for all events that occurred between 10 and 11 am irespective of which day the event occurred. E.g. Event 1 on May 1st 10:17, Event 2 on May 3rd 10:23, Event 3 on May 7th 10;11 and so on...

Comment: Aaah got it. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to Magnus who pointed me to looking at scripted fields. Take a look at:
https://www.elastic.co/blog/kibana-4-beta-3-now-more-filtery

or

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.3/search-request-script-fields.html

Unfortunately you can not use these scripted fields in queries but only in visualisations.

So I resorted to a workaround and use logstashs drop filter to remove the events I don't want to show up in Kibana in the first-place. That is not perfect for obvious reasons but it does the job.