# How to aggregate fields based particular date in every year in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I'm having data in my index from 2010 to 2015.

I have used following code to get the aggregated first name details in every year from 2010 to 2015, it works as expected

```
POST profile/_search
{
  "size": "0",
  "aggs": {
    "count_by_year": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "logdate",
        "interval": "year",
        "format": "yyyy"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "count_by_firstname": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "profile.firstname"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

how to aggregate my data based on particular date in every year.

For Example, I would like to retrieve data **from Feb. 15 to Apr. 15 in every year.**

Comment: Is `logdate` ISODATE formatt?

Comment: The date is in YYYYMMDD format. Example: 20141231

Comment: Do you still want to aggregate by year, but restrict results to only a portion of each year? Or do you want to aggregate by day? week? month?

Comment: Aggregate by year with particular day and month

Answer (score 4):

You may try to use a [`filter` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) with a [`script` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-filter.html) like this. Note that February 15th is the 46th day of the year and April 15th is the 105th day of the year (with an exception on leap years of course, but this illustrates a solution).

The `script` will take any document with a `logdate` between Feb 15th and Apr 15th (of any year) and then the `date_histogram` will dispatch them in the proper year buckets. Finally, the `terms` aggregation splits the counts by first names.

```
{
  "size": "0",
  "aggs": {
    "specific_period": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": "doc.logdate.date.dayOfYear >= 46 && doc.logdate.date.dayOfYear <= 105"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "byyear": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "logdate",
            "interval": "year",
            "format": "yyyy"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "count_by_firstname": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "profile.firstname"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If possible provide me some constant solution please.

Comment: Is it possible to aggregate based on day of month?

Comment: Yes, simply use `doc.logdate.date.dayOfMonth` instead

Comment: can we able to achieve this without using script

Answer (score 2):

[date range](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-daterange-aggregation.html) aggregation with range as below :

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "range": {
            "date_range": {
                "field": "logdate",
                "format": "YYYYMMDD",
                "ranges": [
                    {
                        "from": "20150201"
                    },
                    {
                        "to": "20150430"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "aggs": {
                "count_by_firstname": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "profile.firstname"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that searches for a particular date range in EVERY year. This only searches for one specific range. The OP's question as I understood was for a query that "just" takes day and month as a range. I have a similar question look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30396242/how-to-do-a-time-range-search-in-kibana